# What does "Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports" mean?

Tags: r, exception, roxygen2

When building a package, I got the error

```
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: FooBarBaz
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 13):

This error occurs when you try to export an object that doesn't exist.  That is, the package `NAMESPACE` file contains the line

```
export(FooBarBaz)
```

but `FooBarBaz` doesn't exist in the package.

---

One case where this error can occur is when you are trying to create a common help page for several functions using `roxygen2`.  In the example below, `f` and `g` are related functions to be documented in the `WidgetUtils` page.

```
#' Widget-related functions
#' 
#' Utility functions to assist working with widgets.
#' @param x An input.
#' @return A value.
#' @name WidgetUtils
#' @export
NULL

#' @rdname WidgetUtils
#' @export
f <- function(x)
{
  x + 1
}

#' @rdname WidgetUtils
#' @export
g <- function(x)
{
  x - 1
}
```

The mistake in this code chunk is the inclusion of the `@export` tag in the `WidgetUtils` roxygen block.  This tells roxygen to generate the export line in the `NAMESPACE` file, but its value is `NULL`, so there is nothing to export.  By removing the `@export` line, so the code will work correctly.

Comment: This dind't help me out

Comment: @MarcinKosiński If this answer doesn't fit your needs, then either 1) Work out what has gone wrong in your case and update the answer (it's a community wiki, so feel free to edit), or 2) Ask a new question describing your problem, and including a minimal reproducible example.  Otherwise you're just trolling.

Answer (score 7):

Be careful not to have any commented lines that begin with an apostrophe!

By bad luck, inside my function I had commented out a line that began with an apostrophe (in front of 'Battlestar Galactica' in my fake example) so it look like this:

```
#' @export
getMyFavoriteSciFiShows <- function() {
  myFavoriteSciFiShows <-
    c('Star Trek Next Generation',
      #'Battlestar Galactica',
      'Babylon 5')
  return(myFavoriteSciFiShows)
}
```

This really screwed up roxygen2 v 6.0.1 since it did not signal any errors and this is what it put into my NAMSEPACE file:

```
export("Galactica',")
export(Battlestar)
```

Not only was my desired export myFavoriteSciFiShows missing but two erroneous ones were added. These erroneous ones can result in undefined exports.

Comment: Can you provide an example of when `#' @export` fails?

Comment: @RichieCotton \@export can fail [if the function contains a commented line that begins with an apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42513528/283973).

Comment: @RichieCotton I replaced my entire answer in response to your question once I figured out why my export was having trouble. Thanks!

Comment: It is a good idea to use hash + space for comments. CTRL+SHIFT+C (CMD+SHIFT+C on macOS) does this in RStudio.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very stupid typo: in roxygen2 skeleton, I copied what was meant to go into `#' @return` field, to `@export`.

Should have been:

```
#' @return new data frame
#' @export
```

Instead, I had:

```
#' @return
#' @export new data frame
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed a function, and roxygen2 didn't seem to remove it from the NAMESPACE file. Go in there and delete that line manually and it will fix the error

Answer (score -1):

There has alternative way, download package from GitHub repo, and then `Install & Restart`