# roxygen2: function not exported to NAMESPACE even after using @export

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am building a package and get an error, saying that a function is not an exported object of the package.
In the R script, I have used @export tag to export the function, however when I roxigenise using document() or roxygen() the function is not exported to the NAMESPACE (the Rmd file for that function is created though).

Comment: Does `your_package:::your_function` work after loading your package?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, as I read, it is not suggested to do so @jakub

Comment: Indeed. Just checking. Are you defining method for some S3 class? Also, it may be useful to post the roxygen block here.

Comment: Yes, I am. Do you mean I should post the R script or the NAMESPACE? @jakub

Comment: Found the issue. It was a very stupid one. When I wrote the R script there was an additional space before writing the codee. e.g. #'  export rather than #' export

Comment: @Rospa your comment is confusing as it does not include the @ symbol before export and your comparison looks identical (both have one space). Perhaps this was because of the markdown formatting.

Comment: [This is a helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593278/roxygen2-not-creating-rd-documentation). For me, the problem was the unticked box 'roxygenise when install and restart'

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. It turned out that inside my function I had commented out a line that began with an apostrophe (in front of 'Battlestar Galactica' in my fake example) so it look like this:

```
#' @export
getMyFavoriteSciFiShows <- function() {
  myFavoriteSciFiShows <-
    c('Star Trek Next Generation',
      #'Battlestar Galactica',
      'Babylon 5')
  return(myFavoriteSciFiShows)
}
```

This really screwed up roxygen2 v 6.0.1 since it did not signal any errors and this is what it put into my NAMSEPACE file:

```
export("Galactica',")
export(Battlestar)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too. My impression is that roxygen attempts to interpret ANY appearance of #' and this often messes up @export and other things.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me then I ran

```
devtools::document()
```

and click `check` from the `Build` tab the problem got solved.

I am giving this answer to someone who may have this same problem and search for this. It may help.